# How to change my default home directory

Tags: home-directory

[image]

Right now "collin-blatt" has the home icon on it. That is where my files are located by default. I want to delete that and make "collinblatt" the default.

Comment: This is so because by default the "home directory" has the same name of your username. It can be changed, but well, I would not recommend that to a new unix user. Couldn't you change your username?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a thinking - error ;)

I assume you have two `collin-` user accounts: collin-blatt and collinblatt.

If you login as `collinblatt`, the home icon will be on the `collinblatt` folder, if you login as `collin-blatt`, it will be on the `collin-blatt` folder. That has nothing to do with a presumed "default home directory"; it is always on the current user's home folder.

If you indeed have two user accounts, move your important files to the `collinblatt` folder and login as collinblatt, remove the `collin-blatt` account.

If you created the folder:`collinblatt` manually, remove it, create a new user account (with administrator's permissions) `collinblatt`, login into the new account, copy the files into the new user's home directory and remove the `collin-blatt` account from your new account.

The only thing you have to keep in mind is that if you have internal references inside your `collin-blatt` folder, they will have to be edited, since your username is different. Therefore I would not copy the contents of the folders 1:1, but just move the files.

Comment: You **can** have user 'joe' with home dir 'jack', if you really want... you know, the old shoot-in-your-foot unix philosophy. `man usermod`, flag `--home`.

Comment: @Rmano really? That is new to me! but.. I am looking at it. That seems actually what he is asking for, shouldn't you answer it?

Comment: ...let see why he wants to do that. Breaking the assumptions that `$HOME` is different to `/home/$USER`, although perfectly correct, can lead to surprises in poorly written scripts...

Answer (score 4):

These are terse instructions on purpose, because they are in the category "do that only if you *exactly* know what you are doing". So you are not supposed to cut and paste them...

In Ubuntu systems, a normal user(1) 'joe' has as home directory '/home/joe'. You can change that so that user  'joe' has as home directory '/home/jack', but you can find problems onward --- you have been warned.

To do that, logout from your user 'joe'. Log in with another user (an administrative one), and from a terminal do

```
man usermod
```

and study it, especially the flags `-m` and `--home`. If still convinced, do

```
usermod --move-home --home /home/jack joe
```

with the obvious `sudo` in front of it.

*(1) notice that this is not true for system user, like 'root'.*

Comment: Hi i wanted to move my home dir for auto_deploy from /mnt/home to /home .... i tried  usermod --move-home --home /home/auto_deploy/ auto_deploy ....... it didn't worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I will explain the full steps for modifying the home directory defined as `$HOME` for let us say user `elise`. The default directory of this `admin user` was set by the System install of Ubuntu and is `/home/elise` as seen from the Terminal cmd. line:

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/elise
```

Now I want it to be `/home/ubuntu-xenial/elise`. I use this in order to properly upgrade to a newer release of Ubuntu, as you can perform this way, a fresh install and later move the `hidden files` from your previous home directory following an automatic install of all packages installed in the previous Ubuntu release.

To check the user modification use:

```
$ sudo grep -E --color 'elise' /etc/passwd
elise:x:1000:1000:Elise,,,:/home/elise:/bin/bash
```

First you cannot modify a logged user. So if you don't have another `admin user` you will have to create one. We will create here a `tempuser` with a home directory to properly login, using [useradd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/useradd.8.html), so we will use the `-m, --create-home` option. As seen in the manpage there is a long and abbreviated command name, here are both (Use only one):

```
$ sudo useradd --home-dir /home/tempuser --create-home --shell /bin/bash --groups sudo tempuser
$ sudo useradd -d /home/tempuser -m -s /bin/bash -G sudo tempuser
```

Then we create a password for tempuser:

```
$ sudo passwd tempuser
```

Type in a new password for the temporary user when prompted. Reboot and log in as `tempuser`. Then, open up a Terminal.

We first create the `new path for home directory`, not the `new home directory` as it will be created automatically by [usermod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/usermod.8.html) if it is does not already exist:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /home/ubuntu-xenial
```

Then we create the `new home directory` and move all the content of the previous one (long and abbreviated command - Use only one):

```
$ sudo usermod --home /home/ubuntu-xenial/elise --move-home elise
$ sudo usermod -d /home/ubuntu-xenial/elise -m elise
```

Check the update:

```
$ sudo grep -E --color 'elise' /etc/passwd
elise:x:1000:1000:Elise,,,:/home/ubuntu-xenial/elise:/bin/bash
```

Success, the files and folders have been moved with the appropriate ownership. Then reboot as your regular login here `elise` and remove the tempuser, as you no longer need it.

```
$ sudo userdel tempuser
```

As a home folder was created:

```
$ sudo rm -r /home/tempuser
```

That's it.