# two users in home directory

Tags: upgrade, directory, home-directory

I have two users in my home folder: one is called "nico" (new username after release upgrade) and the other is called "nicolo" (old username).

In the "nico" folder there is small home picture, is seems to be the standard one and inside there are no contents in the single folders (Documents, Images, ect.). In the "nicolo" folder there are all my old datas.

How can I merge the two folders? Or at least just see and use the one with my old data as standard.

Thanks,
Nico

EDIT: When I type `ll /home` I get:

```
total 40
   drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 set 28 23:19 ./
   drwxr-xr-x 24 root root  4096 set 29 08:25 ../
   drwxr-xr-x 23 nico nico  4096 set 29 10:09 nico/
   drwxr-xr-x 58 nico nico 24576 set 27 13:52 nicolo/
```

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 is End-of-Life. However, your question is not Ubuntu version specific, so just remove all the 12.10/13.10 mentions in your post and upgrade to 14.04 in the meantime.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/449942/how-to-change-my-default-home-directory/449998#449998

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rsync` to sync the two directories:

```
rsync -aP /home/nicolo/ /home/nico
```

Once you're satisfied that all the data is now available in your new home directory, feel free to delete the old one (`rsync` has an option to delete files after copying, but still...). Also note [the `/` after `nicolo`](https://serverfault.com/a/529295) - it's needed to make `rsync` sync the directories instead of making a `nicolo` directory inside `nico`.

Comment: problem solved as you said, I just had to write down the complete path: `rsync -aP /home/nicolo/ /home/nico`

Comment: @nicoquei Hmmm. I assumed you would work from `/home`, but you're right, it's better to specify the full path. Updating.