# How to change my home directory?

Tags: command-line, ssh, home-directory, bashrc

I have a current /home/user/ directory for ~ but I want to change it to be at /user/home/

/user/home already exists.

The option of using `usermod` is not going to work because I don't have access to the system as root or as another user.

I am asking for a solution along the lines of modifying some .bashrc file and changing some environment variable or smth similar. I log in via ssh.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Thank you in advance

Solutions like the ones below unfortunately aren't applicable to my case:

[How to change my own home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512098/how-to-change-my-own-home-directory)

[How to change my default home directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449942/how-to-change-my-default-home-directory)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797819/command-to-change-the-default-home-directory-of-a-user

**EDIT**

I thought I'd give some more info here rather than respond to the comments.

Currently the folder structure is a lot stranger than my example above, but the jist of it is the same. Ie currently when I do:

```
user@local:~$ ssh user@host
```

I end up in:

```
user@host:~$ 
user@host:~$ pwd
/path/of/current/home/
```

so when I use things like [`pip` with the `--user` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143077/how-can-i-install-packages-in-my-home-folder-with-pip) it will install things locally.

Because there are some memory limitations as well as `ssh` issues with writing to that location (after some time I can no longer write) I would like to have the following behaviour:

```
user@local:~$ ssh user@host
user@host:~$ 
user@host:~$ pwd
/path/of/new/home/
```

`/path/of/new/home/` already exists and doesn't have the limitations set above.

Comment: I added some extra info to the question to hopefully address your concerns. Let me know if you still have questions

Comment: Thanks for editing the original question rather than putting all that in comments. Ubuntu (and Linux in general) follows strict guidelines on where the user data (and user specific software) can be. It they have to be inside `/home/[userID]/...` folders. If the problem is disk space, you should consider moving `/home/` or some sub-folders to a new partition. Hint, partitions can be mounted as any (sub-)folder. See [Move home folder to new partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive)

Comment: what would happen if I simply changed the $HOME environment variable do you know?

Comment: I don't know if that will work.

Comment: so I have tried setting it and it seems to work. There are three potential locations I tried `.login`, `.bashrc`, `.profile` and only in `.profile` it works. The line I added is `export HOME=/path/of/new/home/` but I'm not sure if that is all I need to do, or if something else gets affected

Comment: I posted a follow up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586518/what-will-happen-if-i-export-my-home-variable-upon-login

Comment: Seems to me the follow up is more suited to [unix.se] or [su] than [so].

Comment: do you know how I can move the question other than the obvious copy paste?

Comment: posted on unix & linux https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175228/what-will-happen-if-i-export-my-home-variable-upon-login

Comment: Definitely the easiest way would be to ask the person who has root access to your system to run the `usermod` command for you. Everything else are workarounds that may or may not work.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could just add this line to your `~/.profile`<sup>1</sup>:

```
HOME=/user/home/
```

However, that really isn't a good idea. Problems it would cause include (but are probably not limited to):

1. That will only work if `/home/user` is owned by your user. If it isn't, you won't even be able to log in.
2. This will work for your user only. For everyone else, your home directory will be whatever is stored in `/etc/passwd`. This means that, for example, `cd ~user` will fail. In other words, if I log in as `bob` and `bob` has the line `HOME=/home/bob/foo` in `~/.profile`, then `bob` thinks that his home directory is `/home/bob/foo` but nobody else knows that:

   ```
    $ whoami
    bob
    $ echo $HOME
    /home/bob/foo
    $ cd ## this moves to your $HOME
    $ pwd
    /home/bob/foo
   ```

So far so good. But:

```
    $ whoami
    terdon
    $ cd ~bob
    $ pwd
    /home/bob
```

3. This will drive your sysadmin insane. You do not want to anger your sysadmin for you are crunchy and taste good with ketchup.

In any case, it is rarely a good idea to mess with variables like `$HOME`, as it can often have unintended consequences. Instead, a much cleaner solution would be to make sure every new shell session starts in the target directory. Just add this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
cd /user/home/
```

Now, each time you log<sup>2</sup> in or open a terminal, you will find yourself in `/user/home`.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Or `~/.bash_profile` if it exists.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> Log in to Debian-based systems like Ubuntu, anyway. For other distributions/OSs, you might need to add it to `~/.profile` as well.See [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/432508/85695).